# Why strpos fail in this example

Tags: php, strpos, strstr

I want to clean the url addres but first I want to check if what should be replace is in the string. I want to use strpos because is faster, but it fails to detect the string.

```
$txt = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aWFmXFFjJfw';

if(strpos($txt, 'http://www.')){
echo 'true strpos'; // not shows
}

if(strstr($txt, 'http://www.')){
echo 'true strstr'; // show
}
```

Also

```
$match = strpos($txt, 'http://www.');
var_dump($match); // int(0);
```

Comment: When in doubt, or learning, or have an issue, check the php.net manual to make sure you understand how the function/etc works :) In this case the examples would have fixed your issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it equals 0 which equates to false.

Instead use:

```
if(strpos($txt, 'http://www.')!==false){
    echo 'true strpos'; //shows
}
```